# Is reducer and global variable are the same?

Tags: react-redux, reducers

Can I get the reducer state in Browser console like accessing declared javascript variables.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a middleware to store the redux state in a global variable.

```
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

    const stateInGlobal = store => next => action => {
      const result = next(action);
      window.reduxState = store.getState();
      return result;
    };

    const store = createStore(reducer, undefined, applyMiddleware(stateInGlobal))
```

Now you can access to redux state through the variable reduxState.